# How do I calculate percentage change of a timeseries of daily data

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I have a daily timeseries of indexdata and want to take yearly pct changes of it. If I use `DataFrame.pct_change(periods=...)` I will have to define the exact number of days till the same day last year which is not correct as the number of working days differs from year to year. Do anyone have any idea how to get the changes from the same day a year back ?

The code may look like:

```
import pandas as pd

list=[]
list=[[7.71],[7.79],[6.80],[6.44],[6.46],[6.80]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['index'], index=['2016-01-04','2016-01-05','2016-01-06','2017-01-04','2017-01-05','2017-01-06'])
```

and I want the output as follows:

```
2017-01-04  -16.45%
2017-01-05  -17.10%
2017-01-05    0.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: starting from the good answer from @Pablo C: given OP's definition of the DataFrame, we first need to convert the index to `DatetimeIndex`, otherwise @Pablo C's answer will throw `NotImplementedError: Not supported for type Index`

```
import pandas as pd

list=[]
list=[[7.71],[7.79],[6.80],[6.44],[6.46],[6.80]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['index'], index=['2016-01-04','2016-01-05','2016-01-06','2017-01-04','2017-01-05','2017-01-06'])

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

do = pd.DateOffset(years = 1)
df.pct_change(freq = do).dropna().mul(100)


#               index
# 2017-01-04    -16.472114
# 2017-01-05    -17.073171
# 2017-01-06    0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some recommendations:

1. don't use `list` as a list name because you'll overwrite the built-in `list`.
2. don't use `index` as a column name because in pandas `index` contains the rows identification. Also, it can be confusing since one can access a column with `df.column_name` but in this case it would not be possible because `df.index` contains the dataframe index.
3. Make sure to use [`pandas.DateTimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) when creating a datetime index.

```
l = [7.71, 7.79, 6.80, 6.44, 6.46, 6.80] 
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', 
                          '2017-01-04' ,'2017-01-05' ,'2017-01-06'])
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['col'], index = index)
```

Now, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) with a [`pandas.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/offset_frequency.html) object:

```
do = pd.DateOffset(years = 1)
df.pct_change(freq = do).dropna().mul(100)
```

**Output**

```
                index
2017-01-04 -16.472114
2017-01-05 -17.073171
2017-01-06   0.000000
```